# Emacs modeline box in xresources

Tags: emacs

I use emacs in ubuntu 12.04. i want define some background or foreground in my .Xresources.

When i use:

```
Emacs.mode-line.attributeForeground: #ccc
Emacs.mode-line.attributeBackground: #333
```

it works, now i want to disable mode-line box or set mode-line box color to #ccc.

i googled it and find some:

```
Emacs.mode-line.AttributeBox: off
```

but it didn't work. I just want it in .Xresource file not emacs init file. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the emacs X window instance has a lowercase name by default, it appears that you have to specify the primary resource class using lowercase as well, i.e.:

```
emacs.mode-line.attributeBox: nil
```

Also, you need to use `nil` to disable the box attribute, as emacs throws up an error for `off`. Similarly, you may also need to set `emacs.mode-line-highlight.attributeBox` to `nil` as well if you wish to disable the box attribute for instances when you mouse-over items in the mode line.

Comment: Hi, thank you. use nil to disable the box attribute is correct, but my emacs instance have a name 'Emacs' not 'emacs', so for me, 'Emacs.mode-line.attributeBox: nil' works.

Answer (score 1):

I use emacs24 in ubuntu12.04.

This disable box attribute in mode-line (Thanks Greg E.):

```
Emacs.mode-line.attributeBox: nil
```

This set mode-line box color:

```
Emacs.mode-line.attributeBox: "#333"
```

And this set mode-line background and foreground:

```
Emacs.mode-line.attributeForeground: #ccc
Emacs.mode-line.attributeBackground: #333
```

In my computer, set background or foreground must not use double quotes and set box color must use double quotes. I don't know why.